# How to estimate amount of spark executor on a Hortonworks Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I setup a Hortonworks Hadoop cluster:

- Hortonworks version is 2.3.2.
- 1 NameNode, 1 Secondary NameNode, 10 DataNode
- Spark 1.4.1 and deployed on all data node.
- YARN is installed.

When I run a spark program, the executor is only run on 4 nodes but not whole data nodes.

How to estimate amount of spark executor on such Hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of executors you request is by default 4. If you want to request more, you have to call with the `--num-executors = x` parameter on the command line or set `spark.executors.instances` in the configuration. More details here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

Because the Spark is run on Hortonworks Hadoop with YARN, each Spark client should deploy YARN/node manager, YARN client. Otherwise, the spark client would not be scheduled.

The actual executor is related on the min number of node manager and num-executors.